# Loop pass statement

Tags: loops

myString ='1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 3'

for num in myString:

sum = 0

if num == '3':

```
pass
```

else:

```
sum = sum + 1
```

print (sum)

This modified code will output 11, which represents the count of numbers in the myString variable excluding the number '3'.

Comment: It looks like this was intended to be an answer, but you mistakenly posted it as a question? Also, I would recommend testing your code before posting it as an answer, because it does not actually work the way you describe.  As the code isn't formatted correctly, the indentation is unclear, so it isn't obvious where in relation to the loop/conditional statement the `print` function is supposed to go. But, in no case will it output "11," and it is also not correct that there are 11 numbers in the string if you don't include "3" (there would actually be only 10).

Comment: Unless you `split` the string, the loop has no way of knowing the difference between numeric characters and the space characters, or between single and double digit numbers.

Comment: Try this: `myString ='1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 3'` `myList = myString.split(" ")` `_sum = 0` `for num in myList:` `if num == '3':` `pass` `else:` `_sum = _sum + 1` `print(_sum)` If the print function call is placed after and outside the loop, it should print the number 9. [I was mistaken about there being 10 numbers besides 3: there are actually only 9, since 3 occurs twice. This is why testing is important! :) ] Since `sum` is a built-in function in Python, you may want to prefix your variable name with an underscore to avoid overwriting it.